# OnModelCreating not linking tables together

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework

I want to link my two tables. However, it's not working. I have two models "CartItem" and "Movie" and I want the CartItem to contain a Movie. I am working in Studio Visual on Mac. Thaaaaaanks.

```
namespace Eshop.Models
public class CartItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int MovieID { get; set; }
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; } }

public class EshopContext : DbContext
{
    public EshopContext(DbContextOptions<EshopContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<CartItem>().HasOne<Movie>(s => s.Movie).
    }

    public DbSet<Movie> Movie { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Eshop.Models.CartItem> CartItem { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Eshop.Models.CheckOut> CheckOut { get; set; }

}
```

}

Comment: What exactly is "not working"?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a relation between a CartItem and a Movie. Alas you forgot to tell us what kind of relation: one-to-many? many-to-many?

Anyway, you should declare your Movie virtual.

> In entity framework the non-virtual properties represent the columns of your table; the virtual properties represent the relations between tables (one-to-many,  many-to-many, ...)

A foreign key is an actual column in your table: non-virtual. Movie is not a column in your table of CartItems: virtual

One-to-many relation between Movie and CartItems: a movie has zero or more CartItems, every CartItem has exactly one Movie

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CartItem>()
  .HasRequired(cartItem => cartItem.Movie)
  .WithMany()
  .HasForeignKey(cartItem => cartItem.MovieId);
```

In words: Every `CartItem` in the table that contains `CartItems` has a relation to exactly one `Movie`. This relation is via property `Movie`. Every `Movie` can have many  `CartItems` (zero or more). The Foreign Key to refer to this `Movie` is in property `CartItem.MovieId)`